# Can I select multiple variables in a single Javascript command?

Tags: javascript

Does Javascript have a built-in syntax for selecting multiple variables?

Say I'd like to set a group of variables to equal 0.

Is there some way to combine

> ```
> x = 0
> y = 0
> n = 0
> a = 0
> ```

and so on, into one command?

Or am I getting spoiled by jQuery and CSS-style object selection?

Comment: what JQuery or CSS can do in this issue?

Comment: Both jQuery and CSS have powerful methods for selecting elements on a webpage.

Comment: Yes I know but you are asking about variables not elements on a page

Comment: I'd like to have the same sort of power with variables that jQuery gives me with DOM elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = y = n = a = 0;
```